# How to resolve missing Python module (importlib) for GRASS/Sextante?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, sextante-qgis-plugin

I have installed the nightly build of QGIS 1.9 from Larry's Dakota Cartography site, and have downloaded the latest Frameworks from William's Kyng Chaos site.

However, I am unable to install the Sextante plugin, and therefore cannot access the GRASS plugin for QGIS.  The Sextante plugin is "Invalid" and requires a missing Python module (importlib).

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?  I know I have not provided all of the information that I probably need to provide, so if additional information is needed, please ask, and I will do my best to provide it.  Many thanks.

QGIS 1.9 GRASS/Sextante Plugin Error, OSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 3):

In the master version, the Sextante plugin is integrated into the application/bundle and may conflict with older versions installed in the .qgis folder.

There are daily versions, not stable by definition, which have errors that, often, are resolved in the next version, or not, and you have installed **one** of these versions .

One of the objectives of these versions is to track the bugs. This is why it is important to report them in the QGIS - Developper list or in [Quantum GIS issues](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues),
that's how the project will evolve.

If you want a stable version, continue to use the 1.8 version until the official release of the new version.

Or, like me, test different daily master versions and report the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your reply and helpful information.  I was actually able to track down the missing Python modules (importlib and psycopg2), and install them.  The importlib module was available from here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/importlib

After downloading the module, it was simply a matter of running the setup.py file with the following command: "python setup.py install"

The psycopg2 module was available from the Python Modules section of William's website, although I did have to first install PostGreSQL 9.1 before downloading and installing the psycopg2 mod.

I am now able to fetch and install the Sextante plugin, and so far, everything seems to be available for use.  I haven't tried it with any data though.  Fingers crossed!